# How to correctly get access token in ShopifySharp .Net library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, shopify

I use https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp .Net library to work with Shopify Api. I just create dev webshop and I want to test some GET methods. In documentation I saw next code:

```
string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
string myShopifyUrl = Request.QueryString["shop"];

string accessToken = await AuthorizationService.Authorize(code, myShopifyUrl, shopifyApiKey, shopifySecretKey);
```

All parameters I understand except first , what code is this , where I should get it?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is basically **Authorization code**

It is with respect to concept of **"OAuth"**

Refer:
https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method in your controller which will receive a callback from Shopify:

```
public ActionResult Callback(string code, string shop) {
    string accessToken = await AuthorizationService.Authorize(code, myShopifyUrl, shopifyApiKey, shopifySecretKey); 
}
```

Then when you building authorization URL, you should set variable `redirectUrl` to the method above:

```
//This is the user's store URL.
string usersMyShopifyUrl = "https://example.myshopify.com";

// A URL to redirect the user to after they've confirmed app installation.
// This URL is required, and must be listed in your app's settings in your Shopify app dashboard.
// It's case-sensitive too!
string redirectUrl = "https://example.com/my/redirect/url";

//An array of the Shopify access scopes your application needs to run.
var scopes = new List<AuthorizationScope>()
{
    AuthorizationScope.ReadCustomers,
    AuthorizationScope.WriteCustomers
};

//Or, use an array of string permissions
var scopes = new List<string>()
{
    "read_customers",
    "write_customers"
}

//All AuthorizationService methods are static.
string authUrl = AuthorizationService.BuildAuthorizationUrl(scopes, usersMyShopifyUrl, shopifyApiKey, redirectUrl);
```

And once user will be redirected to authorization URL, it will open Shopify page where user will be able to install app. Then Shopify will redirect him to your callback method with `code` and `shop` parameters

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do server-to-server authentication with no user input?

Comment: Of course. You should create private App in shopify and you will receive credentials which you can use with ShopifySharp like that  `var service = new ProductService(myShopifyUrl, privateAppPassword)`